# Additional argument in HTML '<script src= >' . What is happening?

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

What exactly is the 'data-client-token' inside this  tag doing? It's not a default argument that is passed to the script src such as async or defer. The name also isn't a valid JavaScript variable name.

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?components=buttons,hosted-fields&client-id=yyyyyyyyyyyy"
data-client-token="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"></script>
```

Thanks in advance

Russeree,

Comment: Why would it need to be a valid variable name? It's an HTML attribute, not a JavaScript variable.

Comment: Thank you, I apologize for the simple question and miss understand the HTML syntax, the answer is very appreciated.

Comment: The HTML as-posted is invalid: there's no terminal `>`  in the `<script>` open-tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [HTML data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

data-client-token is required for [advanced credit and debit card payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/) (hosted fields)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was not interpreting the syntax correctly.